# Why does XORing the red RGB image channel, saving, reloading and XORing again not give back the original image?

Tags: matlab

This is the code I use to change the red value

```
pic=imread('farooq1.jpg');
[imr,imc,clr]=size(pic);

for row=1:imr
    for col=1:imc
        for k=1:clr  
          if(k==1) 
            img2(row,col,k)=bitxor(pic(row,col,k),66);
          else
            img2(row,col,k)=pic(row,col,k);   
          end
        end
    end
end

imwrite(img2,'farooq_scr.jpg');
imshow(img2);
```

But when I use this same code again on the resulting file to undo XORing, the result does not match the original picture.

Please suggest me if you know a better way of doing this.

Comment: Are you saying doing xor with 66 twice should give you back the original value?

Comment: Yes i want to do this but not at the same time in the same .m file. I want to do bitxor with a pic and save it or write it to a different for example "farooq_scr.jpg" file, which i want to read later and do the bitxor with the red color value and get the origional pic.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're unable to recover your original image has nothing to do with the code for processing the red color plane, which works correctly but can be done more efficiently and succinctly using [the vectorized code suggested by Jonas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161435/i-have-changed-the-red-value-in-rgb-but-have-problem-to-get-the-origional/5162712#5162712):

```
img2 = pic;
img2(:,:,1) = bitxor(img2(:,:,1),66);
```

The problem you're having is actually a result of the format you're saving the image file in. By default, [JPEG image files](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imwrite.html#f25-720264) created using [IMWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imwrite.html) are saved using [lossy compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression) to reduce the file size. This results in a loss of image information that makes it impossible to recover your original image when you load that image and reapply your processing.

You can fix your problem by specifying that [lossless compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression) is used when saving your JPEG image, like so:

```
imwrite(img2,'farooq_scr.jpg','Mode','lossless');
```

**EXAMPLE:**

Here's an example using a JPEG image `'greens.jpg'` that's included with the Image Processing Toolbox:

```
rawImg = imread('greens.jpg');  %# Load the original image
subplot(2,2,1);
imshow(rawImg);                 %# Display the original image
title('Original Image');

modImg = rawImg;                           %# Initialize a modified image
modImg(:,:,1) = bitxor(modImg(:,:,1),66);  %# Modify the red plane of the image
subplot(2,2,2);
imshow(modImg);                            %# Display the modified image
title('Modified Image');

imwrite(modImg,'lossy_image.jpg');     %# Save with lossy compression
lossyImg = imread('lossy_image.jpg');          %# Reload the image
lossyImg(:,:,1) = bitxor(lossyImg(:,:,1),66);  %# Reprocess the image
subplot(2,2,3);
imshow(lossyImg);                              %# Display the image
title({'Using Lossy Image' 'to Recover Original'});

imwrite(modImg,'lossless_image.jpg',...      %# Save with lossless compression
        'Mode','lossless');
losslessImg = imread('lossless_image.jpg');          %# Reload the image
losslessImg(:,:,1) = bitxor(losslessImg(:,:,1),66);  %# Reprocess the image
subplot(2,2,4);
imshow(losslessImg);                                 %# Display the image
title({'Using Lossless Image' 'to Recover Original'});
```

And here's the resulting set of images:

[image]

You can see that saving the image with lossless compression allows you to recover the original when you reapply your processing steps. You can confirm that you get back the *exact* same image as the original using the function [ISEQUAL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isequal.html):

```
>> isequal(rawImg,lossyImg)     %# Lossy image doesn't match; returns false
ans =
     0
>> isequal(rawImg,losslessImg)  %# Lossless image matches exactly; returns true
ans =
     1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the new image is of the same class as the old one. Also, you can get rid of a few loops

```
pic = imread('peppers.png');

%# initialize img2 to the same size and same class as pic
%# by making it a copy of pic
img2 = pic;

%# apply bitxor to the red channel
img2(:,:,1) = bitxor(pic(:,:,1),66);

%# write the data
imwrite(img2,'peppers_scr.png')
imshow(img2)

%# show that the reverse works
img3 = imread('peppers_scr.png');
img3(:,:,1) = bitxor(img3(:,:,1),66);
figure %# create new figure 
imshow(img3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried this, it works but i dont want to do bitxor twice in the same .m file. I does not works when i read the file "farooq_scr.jpg" just after writing, for example               img3=imread('farooq_scr.jpg'); when i use this some pixels are still scattered over there. Thanks again.

Comment: All i want is to save a file after just doing bitxor with the red channel, which i could read and do bitxor again to get the origional pic. Thanks..

Comment: @user640247: I do not have your image, so I cannot test your case. However, when I run the code on `'peppers.png'`, which comes with Matlab, everything works fine (see my edit).

Comment: Thanks, it works perfect with the peppers.png but not with my picture, is it a problem with .jpg format ? may i send you the pics?

Comment: @Farooq: maybe. You can also try uploading it as part of your question.